# C# OData set default properties returned by $select

Tags: c#, odata

I'm doing a custom EnableQueryAttribute to block some properties from being queryable:

```
[EnableSpecificQueryable(AllowedSelectProperties = "Id, FirstName, LastName")]
```

It's working, but if no query is sent (only something like http://foo.bar/api/foo), ValidateQuery and ApplyQuery (see EnableQueryAttribute) are never called and the default behavior shows all Properties, what I don't want. How to manage this problem ? Where do I have to write the code for this situation ?

After this, I have some questions about general design. IMO, View Model are really bad when it comes to maintain it. It has a lot of duplicate code and a lot of file for not that much.

**1. What is the best way to limit what properties can be returned by an Action ?**

I really love the idea to simply give a list of property name on each Action than using hundred of view models. Sadly this only apply to GET request and I would like to do the same for post and patch.

**2. How can I apply the same design for POST/PUT/PATCH without using redundant code like View Model ?**

The answer to this question needs to take into account specialized Data annotation for each Action (being able to override Model's data annotation and adding new validations).

I'm working with OData in a Web APi project using Entity Framework Code First.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There are two parts to this solution, GET/read operations and write operations. Lets focus on read operations first.

Inside the custom EnableQueryAttribute there are two methods that you can override that might help in this scenario:

> **OnActionExecuting**
>   Here you can manipulate the url before the WebAPI request is processed.
>   you can easily re-write the url without having to worry about recreating the whole OData context, *but...* you don't have any context information about the controller other than what you have passed in through the attribuite

```
/// <summary>
/// Manipulate the URL before the WebAPI request has been processed.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>Simplifies logic and post-processing operations</remarks>
/// <param name="actionContext"></param>
public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    // Perform operations that require modification of the Url in OnActionExecuting instead of ApplyQuery.
    // Apply Query should not modify the original Url if you can help it because there can be other validator
    // processes that already have expectations on the output matching the original input request.
    // This goes for injecting or mofying $select, $expand or $count parameters

    // Modify the actionContext request directly before returning the base operation
    // actionContext.Request.RequestUri = new Uri(modifiedUrl);
    base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
}
```

My original answer was based on ODataLib v5, I was a little bit naïve at the time and we were allowed to do things differently back then, so I had suggested this override

> **ApplyQuery** This method operates almost at the end of the request, you are given the IQueryable after your controller logic has modified/created the query (which is another valid place in the pipeline to do these types of manipulations)
>   Unfortunately, making changes to the query at this stage can break the default OData Serialization if you change the structure of the result. There are ways around it, but you have to manipulate the ODataQuerySettings as well as the query AND you have to modify the original URL. So Apply Query is now better reserved for passive logical operations that do not need to modify the query, but rather operate on the query, perhaps for logging or some security operations

```
/// <summary>
/// Applies the query to the given IQueryable based on incoming query from uri and
/// query settings. 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="queryable">The original queryable instance from the response message.</param>
/// <param name="queryOptions">The System.Web.OData.Query.ODataQueryOptions instance constructed based on the incomming request</param>
public override IQueryable ApplyQuery(IQueryable queryable, ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)
{
    // TODO: add your custom logic here
    return base.ApplyQuery(entity, options);
}
```

**TL;DR - A Solution for GET Requests!**

1. We want to provide a default $select when none is provided
2. We want to restrict any values for $select to only our specified fields

For this example we will put our logic in OnActionExecuting override, because it will be very simple, we will not need to worry about this logic inside our controller logic, we wont have to manipulate any IQueryable expressions and finally the important one:

> The ODataQueryOptions that are generated by the request URI are used to constrain the response payload during Serialization, so even if we select or include additional fields or navigation properties in our controller logic, the serialiser will constrain the response to only include the fields specified in $select and $expand

And that is what we want to do here, constrain all outputs from our controller so that only a subset of fields are available.

```
/// <summary>
/// Manipulate the URL before the WebAPI request has been processed.
/// AllowedSelectProperties may contain a CSV list of allowed field names to $select
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>If AllowedSelectProperties does not have a value, do not modify the request</remarks>
/// <param name="actionContext">Current Action context, access the Route defined parameters and the raw http request</param>
public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    // Only modify the request if AllowedSelectProperties has been specified
    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.AllowedSelectProperties))
    {
        // parse the url parameters so we can process them
        var tokens = actionContext.Request.RequestUri.ParseQueryString();

        // CS: Special Case - if $apply is requested, DO NOT process defaults, $apply must be fully declared in terms of outputs and filters by the caller
        // $apply is outside of the scope of this question :) so if it exists, skip this logic.
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(tokens["$apply"]))
        {
            // check the keys, do not evaluate if the value is empty, empty is allowed
            // if $expand is specified, and by convention and should not return any fields from the root element
            if (!tokens.AllKeys.Contains("$select"))
                tokens["$select"] = this.AllowedSelectProperties;
            else
            {
                // We need to parse and modify the $select token
                var select = tokens["$select"];
                IEnumerable<string> selectFields = select.Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim());
                IEnumerable<string> allowedFields = this.AllowedSelectProperties.Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim());
                // Intersect allows us to ujse our allowedFields as a MASK against the requested fields
                // NOTE: THIS IS PASSIVE, you could throw an exception if you want to prevent execution when an invalid field is requested.
                selectFields = selectFields.Intersect(allowedFields, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
                tokens["$select"] = string.Join(",", selectFields);
            }

            // Rebuild our modified URI
            System.Text.StringBuilder result = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            result.Append(actionContext.Request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri.Split('?').First());
            if (tokens.Count > 0)
            {
                result.Append("?");
                result.Append(String.Join("&", 
                    tokens.AllKeys.Select(key => 
                        String.Format("{0}={1}", key, Uri.EscapeDataString(tokens[key]))
                        )
                    )
                );
            }
            // Apply the modified Uri to the action context
            actionContext.Request.RequestUri = new Uri(result.ToString());

        }
    }

    // Allow the base logic to complete
    base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
}
```

**TL;DR - Regarding Write operations**

How can I apply the same design for POST/PUT/PATCH without using redundant code like View Model ?

We can't really affect write operations as easily in the EnableQueryAttribute, we can't use *ApplyQuery* override, because this executes after the action

> *(yes you can still return a query from a POST/PUT/PATCH if your controller chooses to do so - lets argue about that later)*

But we also cannot modify the POST/PUT in the *OnActionExecuting* before the request because the structure might nolonger match the model and the data will not be serialized and passed on to your controller.

This will have to be handled in your controller logic, but you could easily do this in a base class either to reject the request if the user attempts to provide the fields, or to ignore them, here is an example of a base class handling these rules.

```
/// <summary>
/// Base controller to support AllowedSelectProperties 
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TContext">You application DbContext that this Controller will operate against</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="TEntity">The entity type that this controller is bound to</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="TKey">The type of the key property for this TEntity</typeparam>
public abstract class MyODataController<TContext, TEntity, TKey> : ODataController
    where TContext : DbContext
    where TEntity : class
{
    public string AllowedSelectProperties { get; set; }

    protected static ODataValidationSettings _validationSettings = new ODataValidationSettings() { MaxExpansionDepth = 5 };
    private TContext _db = null;
    /// <summary>
    /// Get a persistant DB Context per request
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>Inheriting classes can override RefreshDBContext to handle how a context is created</remarks>
    protected TContext db
    {
        get
        {
            if (_db == null) _db = InitialiseDbContext();
            return _db;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create the DbContext, provided to allow inheriting classes to manage how the context is initialised, without allowing them to change the sequence of when such actions ocurr.
    /// </summary>
    protected virtual TContext InitialiseDbContext()
    {
        // Using OWIN by default, you could simplify this to "return new TContext();" if you are not using OWIN to store context per request
        return HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Get<TContext>();
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Generic access point for specifying the DBSet that this entity collection can be accessed from
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected virtual DbSet<TEntity> GetEntitySet()
    {
        return db.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Find this item in Db using the default Key lookup lambda
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key">Key value to lookup</param>
    /// <param name="query">[Optional] Query to apply this filter to</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected virtual async Task<TEntity> Find(TKey key, IQueryable<TEntity> query = null)
    {
        if (query != null)
            return query.SingleOrDefault(FindByKey(key));
        else
            return GetEntitySet().SingleOrDefault(FindByKey(key));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Force inheriting classes to define the Key lookup
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>protected override Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> FindByKey(TKey key) =>  => x => x.Id == key;</example>
    /// <param name="key">The Key value to lookup</param>
    /// <returns>Linq expression that compares the key field on items in the query</returns>
    protected abstract Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> FindByKey(TKey key);

    // PUT: odata/DataItems(5)
    /// <summary>
    /// Please use Patch, this action will Overwrite an item in the DB... I pretty much despise this operation but have left it in here in case you find a use for it later.
    /// NOTE: Default UserPolicy will block this action.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key">Identifier of the item to replace</param>
    /// <param name="patch">A deltafied representation of the object that we want to overwrite the DB with</param>
    /// <returns>UpdatedOdataResult</returns>
    [HttpPut]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Put([FromODataUri] TKey key, Delta<TEntity> patch, ODataQueryOptions<TEntity> options)
    {
        Validate(patch.GetInstance());
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return BadRequest(ModelState);

        Delta<TEntity> restrictedObject = null;
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.AllowedSelectProperties))
        {
            var updateableProperties = AllowedSelectProperties.Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim());
            /*****************************************************************
                * Example that prevents patch when invalid fields are presented *
                * Comment this block to passively allow the operation and skip  *
                * over the invalid fields                                       *
                * ***************************************************************/
            if (patch.GetChangedPropertyNames().Any(x => updateableProperties.Contains(x, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
                return BadRequest("Can only PUT an object with the following fields: " + this.AllowedSelectProperties);

            /*****************************************************************
                * Passive example, re-create the delta and skip invalid fields  *
                * ***************************************************************/
            restrictedObject = new Delta<TEntity>();
            foreach (var field in updateableProperties)
            {
                if (restrictedObject.TryGetPropertyValue(field, out object value))
                    restrictedObject.TrySetPropertyValue(field, value);
            }
        }

        var itemQuery = GetEntitySet().Where(FindByKey(key));
        var item = itemQuery.FirstOrDefault();
        if (item == null)
            return NotFound();

        if (restrictedObject != null)
            restrictedObject.Patch(item); // yep, revert to patch
        else
            patch.Put(item);

        try
        {
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!ItemExists(key))
                return NotFound();
            else
                throw;
        }
        return Updated(item);
    }

    // PATCH: odata/DataItems(5)
    /// <summary>
    /// Update an existing item with a deltafied or partial declared JSON object
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key">The ID of the item that we want to update</param>
    /// <param name="patch">The deltafied or partial representation of the fields that we want to update</param>
    /// <returns>UpdatedOdataResult</returns>
    [AcceptVerbs("PATCH", "MERGE")]
    public virtual async Task<IHttpActionResult> Patch([FromODataUri] TKey key, Delta<TEntity> patch, ODataQueryOptions<TEntity> options)
    {
        Validate(patch.GetInstance());
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return BadRequest(ModelState);

        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.AllowedSelectProperties))
        {
            var updateableProperties = AllowedSelectProperties.Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim());
            /*****************************************************************
                * Example that prevents patch when invalid fields are presented *
                * Comment this block to passively allow the operation and skip  *
                * over the invalid fields                                       *
                * ***************************************************************/
            if (patch.GetChangedPropertyNames().Any(x => updateableProperties.Contains(x, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
                return BadRequest("Can only Patch the following fields: " + this.AllowedSelectProperties);

            /*****************************************************************
                * Passive example, re-create the delta and skip invalid fields  *
                * ***************************************************************/
            var delta = new Delta<TEntity>();
            foreach (var field in updateableProperties)
            {
                if (delta.TryGetPropertyValue(field, out object value))
                    delta.TrySetPropertyValue(field, value);
            }
            patch = delta;
        }

        var itemQuery = GetEntitySet().Where(FindByKey(key));
        var item = itemQuery.FirstOrDefault();
        if (item == null)
            return NotFound();

        patch.Patch(item);

        try
        {
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!ItemExists(key))
                return NotFound();
            else
                throw;
        }

        return Updated(item);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Inserts a new item into this collection
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item">The item to insert</param>
    /// <returns>CreatedODataResult</returns>
    [HttpPost]
    public virtual async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(TEntity item)
    {
        // If you are validating model state, then the POST will still need to include the properties that we don't want to allow
        // By convention lets consider that the value of the default fields must be equal to the default value for that type.
        // You may need to remove this standard validation if this.AllowedSelectProperties has a value
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.AllowedSelectProperties))
        {
            var updateableProperties = AllowedSelectProperties.Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim());
            /*****************************************************************
                * Example that prevents patch when invalid fields are presented *
                * Comment this block to passively allow the operation and skip  *
                * over the invalid fields                                       *
                * ***************************************************************/
            // I hate to use reflection here, instead of reflection I would use scripts or otherwise inject this logic
            var props = typeof(TEntity).GetProperties();
            foreach(var prop in props)
            {
                if (!updateableProperties.Contains(prop.Name, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    var value = prop.GetValue(item);
                    bool isNull = false;
                    if (prop.PropertyType.IsValueType)
                        isNull = value == Activator.CreateInstance(prop.PropertyType);
                    else
                        isNull = value == null; 
                    if(isNull) return BadRequest("Can only PUT an object with the following fields: " + this.AllowedSelectProperties);
                }
            }

            /***********************************************************************
                * Passive example, create a new object with only the valid fields set *
                * *********************************************************************/
            var sanitized = Activator.CreateInstance<TEntity>();
            foreach (var field in updateableProperties)
            {
                var prop = props.First(x => x.Name.Equals(field, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
                prop.SetValue(sanitized, prop.GetValue(item));
            }
            item = sanitized;
        }

        GetEntitySet().Add(item);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Created(item);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Overwritable query to check if an item exists, provided to assist mainly with mocking
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected virtual bool ItemExists(TKey key)
    {
        return GetEntitySet().Count(FindByKey(key)) > 0;
    }

}
```

That's a cut-down version of the base class that I use in my Applications, just simplifies generic CRUD actions. I apply a bunch of other security trimming and stuff, but for the GET operations I swear by the OnActionExecuting solution, it's faster to execute than anything else I can come up with because it happens before the action is parsed.

Comment: I simply did a custom action filter and implementing on action executing. There we can get the received model and list every property received and compare it to a list of allowed propertis to post patch or put. After we can load the current entity and map only on allowed properties and save. For patch in odata, the delta<TEntity> can give us the modified properties and we can do the same thing from there.

Comment: I did this differently, my base controller class calls an abstract method ApplyUserPolicy(patch, ODataOperation.Overwrite) then in each class I override this method in the entity controller with logic to do the validation, if any is needed. (just throws exceptions if not valid) So In my implementation I can still use your attirbute and have the base class do this validation unless the controller overrides it. My business case was that different user contexts and states of the data item mean that different fields are available for editing at different times.